# How to detect a word using strstr but by alphabets in C

Tags: c

Hello i got this function from string.h , I use it as a pointer to detect the existence of a word

`p = strstr(string, "WORD");`

Then in the same code I have left another line

```
  p = strstr(chaine, "word");
```

in order to detect the word in capitals and low capitals. But the issue is, I realized that the user can put Word or WoRD or WorD etc etc so the line won't detect it. Basically how to use that function in order to all the cases of writing the word. If that's not possible, are there other functions from string.h to help detect this?

Comment: If there was a library function to do everything, there wouldn't be programmers.

Comment: One method is you can use tolower() function, but do not apply this on string and word itself otherwise these both will be modified, rather use two temporary variables and store them there and then apply strstr() functionality on two of the temporary variables and if result is NULL, then you can give feedback that word is not present in any form in string.

Comment: There is `strcasestr` which does a case insensitive `strstr`. How would that not be applicable? That is, for what data would that produce a false positive or false negative? For example, that would match: `strcasestr("a wOrd game","word")` Or, do you want matches _only_ for: `a word game` or `a Word game`? And, do you want _whole word_ matches, so that `a wordy person` would _not_ match? Please edit your question and provide [in a code block] sample input data for all edge cases and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

mystrstr is a standard implementation.

```
int strneq(const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t len)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*str2 && len--)
    {
        if(toupper((unsigned char)*str1) != toupper((unsigned char)*str2))
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return result;
}

char *mystrstr(const char *s, const char *find)
{
    char c, sc;
    size_t len;
    if ((c = *find++) != 0) {
        len = strlen(find);
        do {
            do {
                if ((sc = *s++) == 0)
                    return (NULL);
            } while (sc != c);
        } while (strneq(s, find, len) != 0);
        s--;
    }
    return ((char *)s);
}
```

or

```
char *mystrstr(const char *s, const char *find)
{
    char *str = strdup(s), *wrk = NULL, *findu = strdup(find);
    if(str && findu)
    {
        wrk = str;
        while((*wrk = toupper((unsigned char)*wrk))) wrk++;
        wrk = findu;
        while((*wrk = toupper((unsigned char)*wrk))) wrk++;
        wrk = strstr(str, findu);
    }
    free(str);
    free(findu);
    return wrk;
}
```